# How to send a push notification for a fixed hour?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm new IOS developer, and i never worked before with push notification or local.

The user need to set a hour, for taken the push notification. 
What need to do my application?

My application, sent everyday for every user who set before the hour a push notification. The push notification is always same.

Can anyone help me? How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, but I think that you are talking about local, not remote notification... For selecting time of notification, you can use this useful guide http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/ especially UILocalNotification's fireDate attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link for refrence to set local notification :

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

//Replace following method in Appdelegate.m in First link's code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (locationNotification) {
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I downloaded both source code, and nothing.  No one is returning a local notification

Comment: Register local notification code are not added in above source code. So i have added few lines for is and iOS8 local notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for local notification

```c
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;

UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
note.alertBody = @"Say Hello!";
note.fireDate = date;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:note];
```

Also you can use framework from parse.com for remote notifications